# Gitlab - CI and CD changes in the repo are not being taken by the remote server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to connect my GitLab repo to my remote ubuntu server in a way that every time I make a new commit to the repo the pipeline gets triggers and deploys the latest changes into my remote server.

I believe I have successfully connected the pipeline to the remote server via **SSH**, **however every time the pipeline triggers I don't see any changes on files of the remote server.**

Below is my complete **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```html
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - pwd
    - git reset --hard origin/mysprint
    - echo "Going to deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://xxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/

  only:
    - sprint1
```

I am executing `git reset --hard origin/mysprint` after the SSH connection to force a git update on the server.

I have also tried with "`git pull origin mysprint`" and it's the same.

Below is the console result of the pipeline task:

```html
Using docker image ruby:2.1 ID=sha256:223dxxxx for build container...
Running on runner-xxxx-project-xxxx-concurrent-0 via runner-xxx-srm-xxx-xxx...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/xxx/api/xxx'...
Checking out xxx as mysprint...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 11
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
Identity added: (stdin) (rsa w/o comment)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
# gitlab.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ pwd
/builds/xxx/api/xxx
$ git reset --hard origin/mysprint
HEAD is now at 70ef5cc update on xx.js
Job succeeded
```

I am guessing, **the reason that I am unable to see latest changes in my remote server is because it's executing the commands inside gitlab docker image itself instead of my remote server. (Using docker image ruby:2.1)**

Comment: And `70ef5cc` is in fact your latest commit hash on that branch?

Comment: @StefanvanGastel, yes, it's my latest commit but the file on remote server remains unchanged. I have a feeling it's not really connected to my server, instead it's doing these job inside the gitlab containers itself.

Comment: it looks like your script is setting up the required SSH (in the before script) but where are the script commands to connect to your server?